# Export Excel PowerPivot recordset as offline cube

Tags: vba, ssas, mdx, powerpivot, powerquery

I have a PowerPivot model that has Power Query as a source. Is it possible to create an offline cube from this?

I've tried creating a pivot table out of the PP and then using the pivotttable.createcubefile method, but get an error:

```
A cube file cannot be created from another cube file. The source "$Embedded$" is a cube file.
```

I've also tried ADODB and ADOMD connections.

For ADODB an approach described here works to write CSV : https://www.kasperonbi.com/export-a-table-or-dax-query-from-power-pivot-to-csv-using-vba/

But I cannot run a MDX query such as

```
CREATE GLOBAL CUBE
```

For ADOMD I tried an approach from here https://www.engram9.info/excel-2007-vba-2/creating-an-offline-cube-using-ado-md-and-vba.html

But the code fails at setting the ActiveConnection property for ADOMD.Catalog object. I use the

```
ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
```

when setting the ActiveConnection property.

Full code that I use atm

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Create_Local_Cube()
    Dim ObjCatalog As New ADOMD.Catalog
    Dim ObjCellset As New ADOMD.Cellset
    Dim StrConnection As String
    Dim strmdx As String

    ThisWorkbook.Model.Initialize

'Create connection string
    'StrConnection = StrConnection & "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=D4SBY981;"
    'StrConnection = StrConnection & "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
    StrConnection = "Provider=MSOLAP.5;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Microsoft_SQLServer_AnalysisServices;Data Source=$Embedded$;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Subqueries=0;Optimize Response=7;Update Isolation Level=2"

'Create the MDX Query

    strmdx = strmdx & "CREATE GLOBAL CUBE [MyCustomCube]"
    strmdx = strmdx & "STORAGE 'C:\MyCustomCube.cub' "
    strmdx = strmdx & "FROM [mergeMarinDs] "
    'StrMDX = StrMDX & "("
    'StrMDX = StrMDX & "MEASURE [Analysis Services Tutorial].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount], "
    'StrMDX = StrMDX & "DIMENSION [Analysis Services Tutorial].[Customer], "
    'StrMDX = StrMDX & "DIMENSION [Analysis Services Tutorial].[Product]"
    'StrMDX = StrMDX & ")"

    strmdx = "EVALUATE mergeMarinDs"

'Feed the cellset object your MDX Query
    ObjCellset.source = strmdx

'Point catalog and cellset objects to the data source using your connection string
    ObjCatalog.ActiveConnection = ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    ObjCellset.ActiveConnection = ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection

'Open Cellset and fill the local cube
    ObjCellset.Open

'Clean up

    Set ObjCatalog = Nothing
    Set ObjCellset = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've also tried extracting the item.data file from a zipped workbook, but I don't know how to recover this file when chaging to .abf format as explained in slide 13 of this presentation https://slideplayer.com/slide/8455428/

Any advice on whether it is possible to export the PP model as an offline cube?

Comment: Can you describe what business need you are trying to accomplish? PowerPivot is pretty much an offline cube already so what feature is lacking?

Comment: I am trying to put the data onto a share drive in hopes that my colleuges can access the same data once it's ready without having to share the workbook.

Comment: do co-workers need to view it one-at-a-time or at the same time? Do you have SharePoint Online licenses for your users? Do you have a Power BI subscription for your users?

Comment: We don't have any other products or platforms. Same time.